# Cassandra UUID from a date

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

How can I create a Cassandra TimeUUID from a date in Java?

I know how to do the opposite using the `toDate(timeuuid)` function, but how do we do the opposite?

Similar to the `QueryBuilder.now()` function, except I don't want the now as date. I need an older date.

Answer (score 0):

There are `minTimeuuid()` and `maxTimeuuid()` functions that convert UUID-like values compatible with `timeuuid`.

```
cqlsh:test>create table aaa (id timeuuid primary key, t text);
cqlsh:test> insert into aaa(id,t) values(minTimeuuid('2018-05-11 10:00+0000'), 't');
cqlsh:test> SELECT * from aaa;

 id                                   | t
--------------------------------------+---
 1119d000-5502-11e8-8080-808080808080 | t
```

See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html) for more details.

Update: it's also possible to use these functions from Java with QueryBuilder, something like this:

```
QueryBuilder.select().fcall("minTimeuuid", your-value)...
```

Comment: Thanks but this is the CQLSH interface, I'm looking for a Java solution

Comment: You can run the same commands via java driver  statements... or you’re looking for query builder?

Comment: I'm looking for the query builder. Anythink in Java will do

Comment: You can just use prepared statements, not necessary to use query builder for everything... But it's also possible to do with query builder, see updated example (not tested although)

Answer (score 0):

```
UUIDs.startOf(new Date().getTime())
```

should return the UUID v4 from given Date in Java

Comment: it does, but when I do:
UUID u = UUIDs.startOf(new Date().getTime());  
Date d = new Date(u.timestamp());

The date is somewhere in the year 4357863

Comment: check this: https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226019-Converting-TimeUUID-Strings-to-Dates

Comment: Note that this timestamp should only be used for querying and is not unique enough for an insert per the docs of com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.uuid.Uuids.startOf - see timeBased method for an explanation on how to do this.